# Asp.net controls in Div tag are not visible when Div tag is visible?

Tags: html, show-hide, radiobuttonlist, selectedindexchanged, asp.net-controls

I'm trying to show/hide a Div tag (which contains other asp.net controls) on a RadioButtonList OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

Issue: When i show Div tag, the controls in the Div tag are not visible. See my code below

.aspx page

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTesting" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblTesting_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Show" Selected="True" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Hide" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<div id="divName" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="James"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Anderson"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

.aspx.cs

```
    Protected Sub rblTesting_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If rblTesting.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            divName.Visible = True
            'lblFirstName and lblLastName labels are not visible?
        Else
            divName.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

I can show/hide individual controls in the Div on selected index changed event. But, my question is why does my controls are not visible when the Div is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The C# code is

```
rblTesting.Visible = false;
rblTesting.Visible = true;
```

The 1st section is the id name of a html tag or an ASP.NET control. If using a html tag you have to add the attribute runat="server" to the html tag